# Hiring manager saying he is "evaluating". How long does it take to get the job offer after the interview?

Tags: job-search, job-offer

Recently, I went into a job interview in a small firm of basically less than 5 people in it. My interview went really well with the decision maker and he told me that he will get back in a week or so.

I sent him a Thank you note the very next day.
After 5 days, I sent him another polite email asking about the status basically. 
He wrote me the following :

"Thanks for the info.  We are seriously evaluating how we can work together and both be successful.  I will get back to you ASAP."

It has been 5 days since that reply and like everyone else in my situation, I have been trying to decode it. Please do let me know what you guys think of it?

Comment: This will depend entirely on the company you interviewed with.  5 days isn't too long, but what is too long is subjective.  If they want to hire you, the won't misplace your contact information I assure you.

Comment: As a suggestion, I would refrain from sending additional reminder emails. That could be seen as too desperate or even become annoying to the recipients. They already told you they will speak to you ASAP, so there is northing you can do to speed their response.

Comment: I've had responses to interviews take as long as three weeks. If it's a small firm, they probably haven't forgotten about you and they're probably moving as quickly as work allows them. Just wait for them to get back to you.

Comment: *We are seriously evaluating how we can work together and both be successful.* - Is code for there are things we like about you but serious concerns as well.  We are unlikely to present you with an offer that will be of interest to you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @DanPichelman - I think that any update that makes this question on topic becomes a duplicate of that question.

Comment: "how we can work together and still be successful" - is the hiring manager an ex-spouse or ex-dating partner? Interesting wording, but maybe it's a translation thing.

Comment: I've heard of situations where hiring decisions dependet on a client signing up for a new project. In that case if the client is hesitant to sign, your hiring manager is hesitant too.

Answer (score 5):

> Hiring manager saying he is “evaluating”. How long does it take to get
>   the job offer after the interview?

As they say: It takes what it takes.

I've been offered jobs on the spot at the end of an interview.
And I've gotten offers 2 months after the final interview.
There's simply no way to know - without asking.

Instead of just imagining, next time ask "Can you tell me what is the process going forward? When can I expect to hear from you?"

> Thanks for the info. We are seriously evaluating how we can work
>   together and both be successful. I will get back to you ASAP.

That tells me that you are being considered, but aren't quite a perfect fit for the role as originally imagined. It's quite possible that they could still come back with an offer of something, but since they haven't yet you need to still keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Keep job searching, they have not made any commitment yet.

Apart from that, there is no set time for them to get back to you, it's purely up to them. I suggest you follow up politely one more time, if you still get a noncommittal response, then don't bank on them ever hiring you and move forwards. They may contact later or not, but there isn't really anything you can do.